# How can i open a bootstrap Model on beforeunload function,

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open Bootstrap model when user close window if user close this model then window will be close.

i tried this,

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
      return  "Bye now!" ;


});
```

this should return a bootstrap model if user close this model then window will close.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload, Simple fact being, you cannot show an arbitrary modal using this event.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the event directly to the window object.
this brings up a dialog box but you can tweak it to open up the bootstrap modal in there.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        console.log(1);
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Any string';
};
```

with jquery

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if(!modalShowing()) {
        //call function to open modal
        showModal();
        //return 'You have unsaved stuff. Are you sure to leave?';
    }
})
```

If you have a JsFiddle for the code I will be more then happy to help implement this.

Comment: I want to open myModel when user cloes the window. and myModel displayed untill user press close or save.